# Unable to set style for <md-app-content> vue

Tags: javascript, vue.js, sass, vue-material

So, I'm unable to set the CSS `overflow:hidden` property for `<md-app-content>...</md-app-content>`.

Here's the snippet of the code that I have:

```
<md-app-content id="main-containter-krishna" md-tag="div">
   <Visualiser />
</md-app-content>

.md-app-container{
   overflow: hidden;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you have `id="main-container-krishna"` your css should be 
`#main-container-krishna{overflow:hidden}`